# Binary Contour Levels

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have a contour data set where the Z values are 0 or 1. I would like to fill in the region where Z is equal to 1. I do not want to do any interpolation.

However, when I use the function

```
    CS = ax.contour(X1, X2, Z, levels = [1])
```

It returns an error that the level is not within the data range. I am unsure how to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: If you want filled contours you need to use `contourf`. If you don't want any interpolation along the edges of your data then you should use `pcolormesh`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib - Contour plot with single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572500/matplotlib-contour-plot-with-single-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using `contourf` with two levels, setting the lower level to zero, and the top level to less than one, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
Z = np.sin(X)*np.sin(Y)

levels = np.linspace(-1, 1, 400)
zdata = np.sin(8*X)*np.sin(8*Y)

plt.contourf(X, Y, 1*(zdata>=0.5), levels=[0,.9]) # polka dot z-values here are 0s and 1s
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For filled values, use contourf. Also, 1 is outside of the data range because it is your maximum level, and contour levels are drawn between ranges. Try:

```
CS = ax.contourf(X1, X2, Z, levels=[0.2, 0.9])
```

Comment: I get the error: ValueError: Filled contours require at least 2 levels.
I'm not sure what value to add such that I don't deal with weird interpolation

Comment: Edited the answer. With those levels and dummy data I just see a clean two color image, no weird interpolation lines.